# How to create a numpy dtype from other dtypes?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

I normally create numpy dtypes like this:

```
C = np.dtype([('a',int),('b',float)])
```

However in my code I also use the fields `a` and `b` individually elsewhere:

```
A = np.dtype([('a',int)])
B = np.dtype([('b',float)])
```

For maintainability I'd like to derive `C` from types `A` and `B` somehow like this:

```
C = np.dtype([A,B])    # this gives a TypeError
```

Is there a way in numpy to create complex dtypes by combining other dtypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the fields using the `.descr` attribute of the dtypes.  For example, here are your `A` and `B`.  Note that the `.descr` attrbute is a list containing an entry for each field:

```
In [44]: A = np.dtype([('a',int)])

In [45]: A.descr
Out[45]: [('a', '<i8')]

In [46]: B = np.dtype([('b',float)])

In [47]: B.descr
Out[47]: [('b', '<f8')]
```

Because the values of the `.descr` attributes are lists, they can be added to create a new dtype:

```
In [48]: C = np.dtype(A.descr + B.descr)

In [49]: C
Out[49]: dtype([('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Thanks! Your method is more concise than mine using list concatenations.

Answer (score 4):

According to [dtype documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html), dtypes have an attribute `descr` which provides an "*Array-interface compliant full description of the data-type*". Therefore:

```
A = np.dtype([('a',int)])    # A.descr -> [('a', '<i4')]
B = np.dtype([('b',float)])  # B.descr -> [('b', '<f8')]
# then
C = np.dtype([A.descr[0], B.descr[0]])
```

Comment: Heh, darn near simultaneous answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a backwater module in `numpy` that has a bunch of structured/rec array utilities.

`zip_descr` does this sort of `descr` concatenation, but it starts with arrays rather than the `dtypes`:

```
In [77]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [78]: rf.zip_descr([np.zeros((0,),dtype=A),np.zeros((0,),dtype=B)])
Out[78]: [('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f8')]
In [81]: rf.zip_descr([np.array((0,),dtype=A),np.array((0,),dtype=B)])
Out[81]: [('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f8')]
```